# How to add legend to geom_point PCA plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Ive made a PCA plot and I am struggling how to get a legend in it (quite new to R)

Here is the code, included is the vector for colours.

```
pca_cols <- c("seagreen3","seagreen3","seagreen3","seagreen3","seagreen3","seagreen3","steelblue","steelblue","steelblue","steelblue")

ggplot(datascores12, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2))+
  geom_point(size=3,fill=pca_cols, shape = 21)+
  xlab(paste("PC1 ", "(",data_exp12[1],"%)", sep=""))+
  ylab(paste("PC2 ", "(",data_exp12[2],"%)", sep=""))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold"),
             legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
             axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold"),
             axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold"),
             axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold"),
             legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
             panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'dashed',
                                             colour = "grey"),
             panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'dashed',
                                             colour = "grey"),
             panel.background = element_blank(),
             axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
             plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 10, hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_blank())
```

To produce this plot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvn4p.png)

I wanted to add a legend at the bottom, cut cant figure it out!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to see a legend, you need to include that parameter in the legend within `aes()`.  So change the `geom_point` line to this:

```
geom_point(size=3,fill=pca_cols, shape = 21)
```

A word of advice:  It is much easier and better practice to let `ggplot` decide how to apply aesthetics for your data points based on a variable within your dataset.  Take the following simple example:

```
# dummy dataset
df <- data.frame(
        x=sample(1:20,20),
        y=rnorm(20,1,0.1),
        group=c('A', 'B')
    )

# color specifications
cols <- list('A'='red', 'B'='blue')

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point(aes(fill=group), shape=21, size=3) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = cols)
```

[image]

`ggplot` decides how to fill in each point based on the location and the variable "group" in the dataframe that is coded as a factor.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know that could happen

Comment: Yes, so you can do a similar thing in your dataset if your original data frame contained a column that gave meaning to the colors.  If you assign the names of those groups to a specific color within a list like the example I used, it will make assigning specific colors easy.  Or, you can just set the aesthetic and let `ggplot` come up with the color scheme and do everything automatically and it will still look pretty nice and be clear.